# Accessing freshly deployed package's library

Tags: octopus-deploy

After Deploy Package step I'm trying to launch a .net core app from a PowerShell script:

```
Start-Process "dotnet" -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList "xxx.dll"
```

The program was not started and it looks like the reason is a current directory is not what I expected. After reading the docs my assumption was that current directory is set to a folder where a deployed package was unzipped. It doesn't seem to be the case... I logged current directory using `(Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName` and got `C:\Octopus\Work\20180502194906-1089-109` which seems to be a temporary folder.

How could I access a library from a deployed package?

Comment: Are you trying to run both deploy and run in the same step?

Comment: @AlexM, script's step comes right after "deploy package" step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is in the same step, then `(Get-Location).Path` should be OK

However if you want to keep in a separate step, then you will need to access through Octopus variables, something like:

```
$OctopusParameters['Octopus.Action[YOUR_STEP_NAME].Output.Package.InstallationDirectoryPath']
```

Or if you installed to a custom directory, then:

```
$OctopusParameters['Octopus.Action[YOUR_STEP_NAME].Package.CustomInstallationDirectory']
```

Comment: Does YOUR_STEP_NAME have to be in quotes?

Comment: as far as I remember not, but been a while I had to work with octopus